# Adding a post var to my home url (for Adwords campaigns tracking) gives me a blank page

Tags: magento-1.7

Any idea why?

www.mymagpage.com/?gclid=iuhgdw287gsdkjna[1]

It has the header and footer, but blank content. How can i debug this?

Answer (score 1):

By default a querystring param should not kill your page render. I would think, then, that some customization or a poorly constructed theme has an undiscovered bug. Try these steps:

- [Enable Magento developer mode](http://www.blog.magepsycho.com/configuring-magento-for-development-debug-mode/)
- Remove one letter at-a-time from the querystring. If the page renders after you've removed the `[1]` you may have an issue with a custom plugin that is trying to grab information from the querystring and getting tripped up thinking you're (incorrectly) defining an array.
- Review the logs at var/system.log and your general PHP log
- Change your home page cms page to another cms page. This is located in System > Configuration > Web
- Ensure there are no javascript errors on the page
- Try both http and https versions of the page and see if the blank content exists in both. If it only exists in https it could be that content (possibly javascript) is being blocked because it's insecure.

You may also want to bookmark this link to follow a standard debugging process:

http://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/magento-debug-process/

Best of luck.

Comment: Yea, sort of sounds like something in `cms/index/index` controller (or overridden) is checking the request too strictly.

Answer (score 1):

There was an issue with my theme coding which i am unable to identify.

I however solved it by modifying the isHomePage() function, adding a check for the request var i that is being sent and makeing it return true.

Comment: Glad you resolved it, hopefully my answer helped you to debug the issue. Please mark your answer as solved.